# Change Python Built-In Depending on Version

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Lets say I have a program that needs to run in both Py 2 and Py 3. The only difference in the functionality is `range` vs `xrange`. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
if version == 3: pass
else: range = xrange
```

I know I saw something like this before, however I can't seem to find an example on the Google machine. 
Thanks guys.

Comment: Check `sys.version_info` tuple if you want to do it manually. Google for `six`, `python-future` or `nine` for 3rd party libraries designed to solve this problem.

Comment: `if range is None: range = xrange`

Comment: I like your answer the best because of the increase in compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major > 2:
    xrange = range
```

Another approach would be to wrap the `xrange` statement in a try/catch block:

```
>>> try:
...     r = xrange(10)
... except NameError:
... # No xrange in Python3
...     r = range(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.version_info`. This is a tuple holding the version number so something like this should work:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    range = xrange
```

If you need a more precise control for the version (minor number), you can either use `major/minor` that give first and second number of the version, or simply `sys.version_info[:2]` that is a tuple that can be used in combination with `==, >=,...`